# masm mov mybyte, -130 why this works?

Tags: masm

Why this code get compiled if there is an error here. -130 does not fit on byte.

```
.686
.model flat,stdcall

.data
mybyte db  0

.code
Start:
    mov mybyte, -130
    ret 0
end Start
```

Comment: MASM appears to only look the absolute value when determining whether to accept the immediate value. The value will be truncated to fit in the destination operand (i.e. one byte) in the generated machine code. Whether this is documented anywhere, I don't know.

Comment: Do you know why MASM looks the absolute value, any reason to do so?

Comment: No. It was just an observation from assembling with different immediate values and then disassembling the result.